# Using "shy" as a verb?

Tags: verbs

> She shies away from new things.

Or

> She shyes away from new things.

Which is better? What is this called? It isn't a present participle because it doesn't end in *-ing*.

Comment: I've generally seen "shied", and that seems to be what most references say.

Comment: Sorry @HotLicks I meant to use it in present form

Comment: Oops.  I think "shies", but haven't checked the refs.

Comment: That’s the third person singular of the present tense, which can be found in any online dictionary … which makes this question off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shy):

> **shy** (intransitive verb)
>
> shied shy·ing
>
> Definition of SHY:
>
> 1. To develop or show a dislike or distaste — usually used with *from* or *away from* (An author who **shies** away from publicity)
> 2. To start suddenly aside through fright or alarm

So for your example, it would be `She shies away from new things.` In the past tense, it would be `She shied away from new things.`

Comment: I shy away from correcting Merriam-Webster, but I would say it means to avoid (or retreat from) something.  Especially used to describe the behavior of animals, such as horses, where a notion of dislike or fear is necessarily an interpretation of an overt behavior.